# JPA: Configuring WildFly 8.x JTA data-source with EclipseLink and Microsoft's SQLServer Database

Tags: sql-server, jpa, wildfly, eclipselink, jta

How to configuring WildFly 8.x JTA data-source properly in order to use JPA with EclipseLink and Microsoft's SQLServer Database?

Answer (score 1):

**A: Configure EclipseLink with WildFly**

1- Download `EclipseLink` jar from [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2- Rename it to `eclipselink.jar`.

3- Download `JipiJapa EclipseLink Integration` jar from [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jipijapa/jipijapa-eclipselink/1.0.1.Final):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jipijapa</groupId>
  <artifactId>jipijapa-eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

4- Rename it to `jipijapa_eclipselink.jar`.

5- Create folder `[JBOSS_HOME]\modules\org\eclipse\persistence\main`.

6- Create `module.xml` in the same folder and paste the following into
it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.eclipse.persistence">
   <resources>
      <resource-root path="eclipselink.jar" />
      <resource-root path="jipijapa_eclipselink.jar" />
   </resources>
   <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.api" />
      <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
      <module name="javax.transaction.api" />
      <module name="javax.validation.api" />
      <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" />
      <module name="org.antlr" />
      <module name="org.apache.commons.collections" />
      <module name="org.dom4j" />
      <module name="org.javassist" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
      <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/> 
   </dependencies>
</module>
```

7- Copy `eclipselink.jar` and `jipijapa_eclipselink.jar` into the same folder.

**B: Configure MSSQL with WildFly**

1- Download `MSSQL JDBC` jar from [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.2.jre8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

2- Rename it to `mssql.jar`.

3- Download `SqlJdbc4` jar from [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

4- Rename it to `sqljdbc4.jar`.

5- Create folder `[JBOSS_HOME]\modules\com\microsoft\main`.

6- Create `module.xml` in the same folder and paste the following into it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.microsoft">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="sqljdbc4.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="mssql.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

7- Copy both `mssql.jar` and `sqljdbc4.jar` into the same folder.

8- Edit `[JBOSS_HOME]\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml` by adding the following datasource (search for `<datasources>` tag and insert the following datasource into it):

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/MyDS" pool-name="MyDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DBName</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>sqlserver</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>username</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
        <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
        <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
        <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
    </timeout>
    <statement>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

9- Edit `[JBOSS_HOME]\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml` by adding the following driver (search for `<datasources>` tag, you will find a `<drivers>` tag inside, insert the following driver into it):

```
<driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft">
    <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

10- Add the following persistence unit into the `persistence.xml` file:

```
<persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>My Persistence Unit</description>
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/MyDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

11- Don't forget to change the following values in steps '8' and '10' above accourding to your preferences: `HostName`, `DBName`, `username`, `password`, `java:jboss/MyDS`, `my-persistence-unit`.

12- You don't have to make any changes to your `pom.xml` file, here is mine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.jpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>JPATest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <finalName>JPATest</finalName>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```